# How can I get the bottom 50% of a select query in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL server I can say:

```
Select top 50 percent
```

How can I say bottom 50 percent?

EDIT - for the sake of an interesting question, if we assume he has a table with a primary key but wants the bottom 50% ordered in **ascending** primary key order. What would be the most efficient way of achieving that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

why not just change the sort order and keep TOP.  Wouldn't that accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 27):

```
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT *

        FROM [Table]

        ORDER BY [Field] DESC
   )
   ORDER BY [Field] ASC
```

Comment: Funny you got no credit for providing solution which returns the bottom half in the original sorting order.  +1 from me.

Comment: +1 for providing the solution to the extension of the question I was adding *before I had completed it* :-)

Comment: 50 minutes later: Wow! The answer made up for lost time ;-),  7 reps for this is now... well "paid".  Funny to see the dynamics of all this.

Answer (score 2):

Your question as stated is technically meaningless because without an order by clause the order in which your data is returned is undefined (in practice most databases will return in primary key order, or if you don't have a primary key then in insertion order, but that is not guaranteed)

Assuming however you have an order by clause but just haven't included it, just would use DESC instead of ASC.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be:

```
Select * From (
    Select NTILE(2) Over (Order by Quantity Desc) as HalfNumber
    From Table1) as NtileTable
where HalfNumber = 1
```

You can then dynamically change the division of your data as you like.

[Check this out.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I dunno whether this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> EXCEPT TOP 50 PERCENT...;
```

And I'm pretty sure something like this would be OK too:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE (ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT ...));
```

Just check the syntax, as I'm only beginning to learn SQL and can't form correct queries without modifying the a million times first ;)