# How to display the last half of the records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To display first half of the records in SQL we use 
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM TableName; 
like wise, is there any solution to **show the last 50 %** of the records, Think that we dont know how may records exists in that table

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388542/how-can-i-get-the-bottom-50-of-a-select-query-in-sql-server ? It's not an exact match (since that one refers to SQL Server specifically), but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: The syntax in your example works only in SQLServer

Comment: mysql and plsql? Really?

Comment: Since you do not provide an `ORDER BY`, you don't need to change anything. Without explicit Order By, there is no "First" and no "Last" rows in SQL.

Comment: Well presumably you have `TOP 50 PERCENT` and then you're missing your `ORDER BY`, right? Otherwise what does `TOP` really mean? So, if you get the "top half" using `TOP 50 PERCENT ORDER BY something;`, you get the "bottom half" using `TOP 50 PERCENT ORDER BY something DESC;`

Comment: And which DBMS are you using? You have `[mysql]` tag, then a `[plsql]` tag and you are using `TOP`, which is valid in SQL-Server and Access.

Comment: There's no such keyword as TOP n PERCENT in Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Just sort it opposite order, and if needed sort again in outer select

```
select * from
(
  select top 50 percent * 
    from table 
  order by col1 desc
) order by col1 asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an ID on the table that gets higher the later the record is inserted:

You will probably have to script it out.  In pseudocode:

```
num = numRecords(table) / 2
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 'num'
```

Or something to that effect, depending on your language of choice.

Either this or some inner selects, which I try to avoid whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

`NTILE(n)` window function is designed for such type of work. It devides resultset into groups with equal number of rows, numbering them from 1 to `(count of rows)/n`.(There is a little nuance when this division doesn't result in whole number. Read documentation.)

```
;with cte as(select *, ntile(2) over(order by colname) as rn from tablename)
select * from cte where rn = 2
```

This means that resultset will be devided into 2 groups, first half will get `rn = 1` and second `rn = 2`.