# how to retrive second half records from given table

Tags: database

how to display second-half records from a given table in oracle

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
WHERE ROWNUM <= (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS);
```

it is displaying first half

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the bottom 50% of a select query in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388542/how-can-i-get-the-bottom-50-of-a-select-query-in-sql-server)

Comment: What criteria do you use to determine which are the top rows and which are the bottom rows?